# How can I let a user choose which fields are required for a form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a CarType and Car category, the user wants to be able to say: if a car is of a specific type, then only show fields X, Y, Z in the CarCreateForm.

This is because  CarType determines which fields are necessary (for instance, a 4 wheel drive has different info).

I am guessing that this has been done before, but I can't find it.

I was thinking storing the choices per field type in a json field on CarType and then dynamically create the form.

Comment: Could you show some code of what you've tried?

Comment: @AhmadMoussa I don't see what code I could give here that is any clearer than my question. I am *looking* for the code.